# Mapbox Load After resize

Tags: mapbox

I have problem with MapBox map
- When I reload my page, map on website have small dimensions. (cca 50x100);
but after when i resize my window, map is full loading.

I will be glad for all advice, 
PS: Sorry for my english.

My Code : 
In index.php

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

in JS :

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = '-AccesToken-';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'ID_map');
    maxZoom: 18
    map.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Are you doing this because you're loading ```display:none?``` If you're waiting for something else to load before the map is loaded, you could try doing that as a callback.

Comment: Another option, can you reset the map size after resize? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/openlayers-redrawing-map-after-container-resize

Answer (score 0):

In current version of Mapbox API you can just call `map.resize();`